# JasperReports: passing datasource (JrBeanCollection Data Source) from Java program to .jasper file

Tags: jasper-reports

Here I am trying to provide the datasource from my Java program to jasper file.

Here is my code:

```java
InputStream reportStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/report2.jrxml");
JRDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(allEnergy_Caliberation, true);

JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportStream);

System.out.println("above error");
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, datasource);
```

I need to pass the datasource in report and wanna print its values.
Similarly in the same jrxml file in **Summary** section I have added the subreport and I also need to provide values for this subreport also.

Please help me out by providing the steps.

Comment: This seems to be a JasperReport bug, you should update yours. More info here:
http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=93821

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have done it..

Actually datasourse was not going in subreport.. so I have changed the property of when no data to all sections,no data...

Then I have passed the collection variable where I have fetched the subreport records...by using `parameters.put("shape_data_all",allShape_Caliberation);`

Then I have created a parameter in main report.. and changed its class to `java.Util.Collection`..

Then in subreport property, `connection type= Use a datasource expression`

`Data Source Expression new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{shape_data_all})`

Then added the fields in the subreport same as I have in the bean properties..